# How many changes have been made in Rails 3.2.1?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I started learning Rails recently. When I read Agile Web Development with Rails (4th Edition), some code is different in Rails 3.2.1. For instance, the JavaScript source is no longer in the public folder. Are there any important changes and what is their impact?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which version of Rails you would like to compare Rails 3.2.1 with. For instance, Rails 2.3.x or Rails 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the asset pipeline. A lot has changed. Most of them were introduced in 3.1

Checkout for a lot of the general ones in

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html